# Form data not reaching Web Api when using Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post form data to an ASP.NET Web API with angular. So I have:

```
<form name="form" data-ng-controller="SubscriberController">
  <input data-ng-model="subscriber.name" name="name" type="text"/>
  <input data-ng-model="subscriber.email" name="email" type="text"/>
  <input data-ng-click="create(subscriber)" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

application.service('SubscriberService', function ($http) {
  return {
    Create: function (subscriber) {
      console.log(subscriber);
      return $http.post('api/subscribers/create', { 'subscriber': subscriber });
    }
  }
});

application.controller('SubscriberController', function SubscriberController($scope, SubscriberService) {
  $scope.create = function (subscriber) {
    SubscriberService.Create(subscriber)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
  };
});
```

Finally on the ASP.NET API I have the following:

```
public class SubscriberController : ApiController {
  [Route("api/subscribers/create"), HttpPost]
  public void Create([FromBody]SubscriberCreateModel subscriber) {
     // Create subscriber
  } // Create
}

public class SubscriberCreateModel {
  public Int32 Country { get; set; }
  public String Email { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }        
}
```

On my angular service I am logging the subscriber and I get:

```
Object { name="john", email="john@something.pt" }
```

The problem is that on the controller both subscriber properties, email and name, are null ...

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: declare $scope.subscriber = {}, inside your controller..

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the data and send the data as url encoded, check my article about how to use web api 2 with angularjs here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En

Hope this helps

Comment: I added the following on my angular config: $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; ... this seems to solve the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create object for **SubscriberController as subscriber** in the html.

```
<form name="form" data-ng-controller="SubscriberController as subscriber">
  <input data-ng-model="subscriber.name" name="name" type="text"/>
  <input data-ng-model="subscriber.email" name="email" type="text"/>
  <input data-ng-click="create(subscriber)" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```